# Large Image is not displaying using wcf

Tags: asp.net, wcf

In the below code i like to display a img using wcf. In which i can able to display only 20kb size image whereas large image greater than 20kb is not displaying pls any one help me to solve this issue.

```
<input type="hidden" id="imgname" runat="server" />
<input type="hidden" id="imgid" runat="server" />

[WebMethod]
        public static string buttonclickImage(string DocumentName,string Documentid)
        {


            string strClientName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientName"].ToString();
            string Docurl = strClientName + "\\Documents\\" +Documentid+"_"+ DocumentName;
            FileServiceClient fileTranz = new FileServiceClient();
            FileDto file = fileTranz.GetDocumentImage(Docurl);
            var fileData = Convert.ToBase64String(file.Content);

            return fileData;

        }
```

Js:

```
function UpdateImage() {

            var Code = document.getElementById('<%= imgname.ClientID %>').value;
            var DOCID = document.getElementById('<%= imgid.ClientID %>').value;
            PageMethods.buttonclickImage(Code,DOCID, onSucess, onError);

            function onSucess(result) {
                //alert("Success");
                document.getElementById('<%=docimg.ClientID%>').src = 'data:image/gif;base64, ' +  result;
            }

            function onError(result) {
                //  alert(result);
               // alert('Something wrong.');

            }
        }
```

Webconfig

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: No i have not received any errors

Answer (score 0):

One day ago i also face same problem.
this is occured due to parameter length in WCF Service Calling.
Modify your web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <readerQuotas
                maxDepth="64"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    ...
</system.serviceModel>
```